# Downloading Excel file from server using servlets

Tags: servlets, download

I have an Excel file on the server side. How I can display it on client side browser using servlets?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 25):

To the point: just get an `InputStream` of it somehow (`FileInputStream` is suitable) and write it to the `OutputStream` of the response the usual [Java IO](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/io/) way. That's basically all. You'll only need to take care that you set the right response headers, so that the browser understands what to do with it. The `Content-Type` header will instruct the webbrowser what kind of file it is so that the browser knows which application to use to open it.

Here's a kickoff example:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String filename = URLDecoder.decode(request.getPathInfo(), "UTF-8");
    File file = new File("/path/to/files", filename);

    response.setHeader("Content-Type", getServletContext().getMimeType(file.getName()));
    response.setHeader("Content-Length", file.length());
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"");

    BufferedInputStream input = null;
    BufferedOutputStream output = null;

    try {
        input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());

        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        for (int length = 0; (length = input.read(buffer)) > 0;) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
    } finally {
        if (output != null) try { output.close(); } catch (IOException ignore) {}
        if (input != null) try { input.close(); } catch (IOException ignore) {}
    }
}
```

Map this servlet in `web.xml` on an `url-pattern` of `/files/*` so that you can get the excel file by `http://example.com/contextname/files/filename.xls`.

If it's actually an `xlsx` file, which isn't by default recognized by the average servletcontainer yet (the `ServletContext#getMimeType()` would then return `application/octet-stream` instead of the desired `xlsx` content type), then you need to add the following entry to the `web.xml` as well:

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>xlsx</extension>
    <mime-type>application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

For a more advanced example of a file servlet you may find [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/02/fileservlet-supporting-resume-and.html) useful as well, it supports under each download resumes as well.