# java excel interaction

Tags: java, excel, com, apache-poi

I'm trying to create Excel file in java. Right now, i'm using Apache POI library to create the file and save it to local drive. Is there a way to start up excel and populate the data without saving it to hard drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this maybe

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ManualXlsxTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
        wb.createSheet("new sheet");
        File tempXlsx = File.createTempFile("temp", ".xlsx");
        wb.write(new FileOutputStream(tempXlsx));
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(tempXlsx);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the approach shown in [*Downloading Excel file from server using servlets*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832715/downloading-excel-file-from-server-using-servlets/2833780#2833780). I've used it for CSV files, but the `xlsx` mime type extension looks appealing.

Comment: i want to assemble the file on client side instead.

Comment: @PP - From the server? You say you're using POI so I'm guessing that's where your code is running.  How would you do that?

Comment: i'm assembling the file at client side using applet. Dont really want to have another trip to server to get the data.