# Where in server is file stored?

Tags: html, file, servlets

When I upload a file using `<input type="file">` in a HTML form and I give the action as `<form action=auth>` where 'auth' ia a servlet. Now I want to know that When user press Submit button where does the file reside? If in Servlet I want to retrieve the file, What should I do?
**Edit**
Now I  read this file(pdf) using java libraries like

```
 public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
 {
try {
      String INPUTFILE=req.getParameter("filename");
      System.out.println(INPUTFILE);
      PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(INPUTFILE);
      int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
      System.out.println(n);

      String str=PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, 2); //Extracting the content from a particular page.
      System.out.println(str);


} <br>
```

But it shows the following error  `java.io.IOException: java_learn.PDF not found as file or resource`

Comment: The web server is getting a `POST` HTTP request. It can do whatever it wants with the data.

Comment: @Basile I want to retrieve that file using servlet? How should i do that?

Comment: I don't know what you call a servlet! Perhaps it is a framework offering you some way of handling the data in the HTTP request?

Comment: public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
 {
    String INPUTFILE=req.getParameter("filename");
    System.out.println(INPUTFILE);
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(INPUTFILE);} Now it is not retrieving the pdf file

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I edited my question for clarification

Comment: where is it giving that error on which line?

Comment: @PrakashK It gives error at this line PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(INPUTFILE); as INPUTFILE just gives the name of file and not the complete path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.4.1) you have to use the POST method and the enctype attribute of the form has to be set to "multipart/form-data".

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-in-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824)  is detailed answer by BalusC to upload file.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832715/downloading-excel-file-from-server-using-servlets)  is kick off example to download file