# When I download Excel from a folder with java I get this error " the format and extension of the .xls file do not match. The file may be damaged"

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xls

as the title says, when I download an excel sheet from a folder I get this message

This is my code

```
RequestMapping(value = "/descargar-datos-entrada/{idSimulacion}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void descargarDatosEntrada(@PathVariable("idSimulacion") String idSimulacion, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties = Util.getProperties("mongo");
        FileInputStream inputStream = null;
        response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Hoja-Resultados-Descarga.xls");

        try {

            Simulacion simulacion = simulacionService.finById(idSimulacion);
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(
                    properties.getProperty("ruta.copia.resultados.excel") + idSimulacion + ".xls");

            int c;
            while ((c = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
                response.getWriter().write(c);
            }

        } catch (SimulacionException | IOException e) {
            Util.autoLogError(e);
        } finally {
            if (inputStream != null)
                inputStream.close();
            response.getWriter().close();
        }

    }
```

and the result .xls file would be as follows:

[image]

I would appreciate some help or advice, Thanks in advance, it is my first question so excuse me if I didn't ask it correctly.

Comment: Please do not use images as code..Why ? Because: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: I thought that with an image it would be much clearer. I will edit the question

Comment: I have accepted your editing suggestion

Comment: never the less . Replace the image with actual code. I just edited your images to be actually shown.

Comment: Try mimetype application/msexcel (or .xlsx)

Comment: Never write binary data using a `PrintWriter`.

Comment: @JoopEggen  I just tried what you indicated and I still get the same error

Comment: @AxelRichter  What type would you use?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832715/downloading-excel-file-from-server-using-servlets/2833780#2833780

Comment: @AxelRichter  I tried it but it didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do binary output with `getOutputStream`, not text output `getWriter`:

```
        Path path = Paths.get(properties.getProperty("ruta.copia.resultados.excel")
                    + idSimulacion + ".xls");
        Files.copy(path, response.getOutputStream());
```