# How to view document of type docx,xslx in JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

I have used the following in xhtml:

```
<pe:documentViewer id="documentViewer" height="380"
            value="#{myBean.fileContent}" />
```

and in Bean:

```
byte[] downloadedFile =handleFileDownload(id);

    fileContent = new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(
            downloadedFile));
```

Using this code I am able to view the PDF files, but how do I view other documents like, **doc,docx,txt,xsl and xslx**?

Comment: Correct, the PE documentviewer just does not support this. Nor will it (unless you find an open source javascript library that can do this and then file a pull request in the PrimeFaces Extensions issue list). How you should show one in the browser should be done the same way as with plain html (but the client-side needs to have a viewer for this)

Comment: e.g. do like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832715/downloading-excel-file-from-server-using-servlets